# Actionlink post to controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

Why doesn't a basic actionlink allow you to post to a HttpPost method within a controller. It seems odd because you are in affect posting back from a view to a controller.

Answer (score 1):

The ActionLink renders an anchor ( tag) and sets the href attribute to point to a specific controller action.  Clicking such a link is not "posting back from a view to a controller" as you state above in your question.  Instead the browser performs a GET request.  This is standard browser behavior.

It is possible to add a click event handler to an anchor (or any element for that matter) which prevents the default browser behavior.  Such an event handler could then perform a POST request in place of the default GET request.  This is essentially how ASP.NET WebForms is built.  Interactions with HTML elements are intercepted and the __doPostBack method is called which in turn makes a POST request.

So to summarize, the ActionLink method does nothing more than render an anchor DOM element whose default responsibility is to perform a GET request to the href when clicked.